# How to implement a relationship between IdentityRole (dbo.AspNetRoles) and a custom entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm working with a project similar to the MVC template project.

I've created some models that I want to be represented in the database. I can create them with a DbContext class just fine, the issue is connecting my class's RoleId with ASP.Net Identity's Role table's id.

Any ideas as to how this is possible?

Comment: Do you want to add an attribute into your Identity's Role class, I mean, extending it?

Comment: Please provide some code, at least code of your entity class. Also explain more detailed what do you what from your entity class and what's the issue that you've run into.

Comment: @Deilan I mean, any code I provide wouldn't really shed much light. If you know how entity framework models are setup, they're really just basic data classes. I'm just looking to make my model's "RoleId" column a foreign key with Identity's role table's "Id" column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say that `RoleDependent` is your entity class. Then:

1) If you need **one-to-many (1:N) relationship** beetween `RoleDependent` and `Role`:

```
public class RoleDependent
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityRole IdentityRole { get; set; }
}
```

that will result in the following migration:

```
CreateTable("dbo.RoleDependents",
c => new
    {
        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        IdentityRole_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
    })
.PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
.ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.IdentityRole_Id)
.Index(t => t.IdentityRole_Id);
```

2) If you need **one-to-one (1:1) relationship** beetween `RoleDependent` and `Role`:

```
public class RoleDependent
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual IdentityRole IdentityRole { get; set; }
}
```

which would result in the migration:

```
CreateTable("dbo.RoleDependents",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Id);
```

Comment: Hey @Deilan, Could you give a many to many sample, because Im not getting the migration output I was expecting.

Thank you in advance.