# How can I create ManyToMany relationship between AspNetRoles and Menus table

Tags: many-to-many, asp.net-identity, one-to-many, entity-relationship, many-to-one

I am using asp.net mvc identity. I want to  create ManyToMany relationship between Roles and Menu table
I found this to create a ManyToMany relationship in EntityFramework between two tables
on
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

```
public class Role
{
    public Role() { }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
}

public class Menu
{
    public Menu()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I am unable to find AspNetRoles Class. My question is how can i create relationship between existing identity tables. ManyToMany, OneToMany and ManyToOne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search Here I found my answer

[How to implement a relationship between IdentityRole (dbo.AspNetRoles) and a custom entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905005/how-to-implement-a-relationship-between-identityrole-dbo-aspnetroles-and-a-cus)

We only have to define this property

```
public virtual IdentityRole IdentityRole { get; set; }
```

in role dependent class which will solve the problem.

The reason for not deleting this post is to cover all possible aspects of the questions for this answer

Comment: Hey @dE Source , when I tried to simulate this scenario the result is that each table create a foreign key reference to each other, and isn't a functional many to many relationship.

How was your DB generated?, Im really confused and I can't find any functional samples out there.

Comment: Hi @HéctorWilliam although the [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) i shared has all the examples pertaining to relationship but if still you are have some problems kindly share your code i will help you out.

Comment: Hello @dE Source, thank you for writing back... I was getting a lot of  trouble trying things the way you described, but fortunately  I'd make it work, Im gonna post my answer right back with the explanation.

And Thank you again!

Comment: Good to know :) if you find this answer useful you can up vote it

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to follow your solution, based of course on the problem you proposed.

I edited the first code you posted in order to get it working properly. I want  to explain the use of the Identities Tables and one proper way to extend or customize them.

**Note:**
This code will work when using **ManyToOne** or **OneToOne** relationships

```
public virtual IdentityRole IdentityRole { get; set; }
```

But I wouldn't recommend it, because you will get some weird and unexpected result at some point of your Model Relationships design.

---

Now I have to say, this was the way it worked for me, I tested a lot and  always got what I wanted.

The trick is easy, Always extend your **IdentityModel**, doesn't matter which one... and then do everything to this model that extended the Original Identity (relationship, referencing, adding properties, ect...).

With all that said, Let's see the sample now:

To get the **ManyToMany** relationship that you where trying to get, you must extend the **IdentityRole** class, and then work with it for customization.

I will focus on the **ManyToMany** relationship example, because I have the feeling is the less common sample out there.

So here we go :

DBContext is the same for both samples:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
      .
      .
      .

      override
      public IDbSet<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
    }
```

Entities:

```
public class Role : IdentityRole
  {
    public Role() { }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
  }

public class Menu
  {
    public Menu()
    {
      this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Which generates this migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Menus",
    c => new
        {
    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
    MenuName = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.AspNetRoles",
    c => new
        {
    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
    RoleName = c.String(),
    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");

CreateTable(
    "dbo.RoleMenus",
    c => new
        {
    Role_Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
    Menu_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Role_Id, t.Menu_Id })
    .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.Role_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Menus", t => t.Menu_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.Role_Id)
    .Index(t => t.Menu_Id);
```

As you can see, there is a pivot table that was automatically created **RoleMenus** and automatically added the respective relationships.

On the other side, if someone follow your example and use the **IdentityRole** to create a ManyToMany relationship, using the ICollection .

Let's see :

```
public class Role : IdentityRole
  {
    public Role() { }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
  }

public class Menu
  {
    public Menu()
    {
      this.Roles = new HashSet<IdentityRole>();
    }

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Generating :

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Menus",
    c => new
        {
    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
    MenuName = c.String(),
    Role_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.Role_Id)
    .Index(t => t.Role_Id);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.AspNetRoles",
    c => new
        {
    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
    RoleName = c.String(),
    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
    Menu_Id = c.Int(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Menus", t => t.Menu_Id)
    .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex")
    .Index(t => t.Menu_Id);
```

As you can see, the relationship created was a trial of a **OneToOne**, not the result we were expecting and if we reference the original IdentityModel to do some sort of relationship, we'll always gonna get it wrong at some point.

So I guess this was it, sorry for the long post, but I felt that somebody should have talked about how to edit the **IdentityModel** or at least in one functional way.

So I hope this helps somebody that run into same necessity in the future.

Sorry for my English.
Regards.

Comment: I am not able to define ManyToMany relationship as you guided in your answer. I am facing below error.
IoTCP.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.